# ¿Cómo solucionar error «Cannot find command 'dotnet ef'» si el paquete ya está instalado?

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-mvc-5, gnu

Estoy trabajando con **ASP.NET MVC 5** y quiero utilizar el Entity Framework. A diferencia del *Package Command* de Visual Studio en Windows, en GNU/Linux está la opción de usar *dotnet ef*, pero aún cuando lo instalo,  me sigue saliendo el mismo error. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: agrega el contenido de tu path

Comment: También dinos que Linux usas, exactamente que instalaste y como lo instalaste. Muéstranos también el error _exacto_ y cuando te sale.

Comment: Lo instalé desde los repositorios oficiales de Archlinux. He instalado dotnet-ef desde el propio SDK de dotnet (`donet tool install --global dotnet-ef`).

Según la wiki de Arch, se debe de poner en nuestro .bashrc el PATH de dotnet (`export DOTNET_ROOT=/opt/dotnet`).

Hasta ahora puedo usar la herramienta invocándola desde la ruta de instalación (`~/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef`), pero no de manera global (`dotnet ef`).